# For a Spanish visa do I need accommodation booked for the day I am due to fly out at midnight?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, proof-of-accommodation

I am trying to obtain a Schengen visa from the Spanish Consulate. I have a flight booked for the Friday morning at 12 am and hence didn't book accommodation for the Thursday.

Will this be a problem?

As a side note: I read somewhere that if you book more hotel nights than the intended period of stay your visa can be refused.

Comment: Personally I will not worry about it.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What exactly is your concern?

Comment: Different people have different conventions for what "12 am" actually means. Do you mean midnight, or noon? If midnight, then of course you wouldn't book a hotel room for that night, you won't be there. If noon, then I certainly *would* book a hotel room, unless I really really wanted to sleep overnight in the airport (I don't).

Comment: 12 am as in midnight and its an international flight so it doesnt make sense to book a room.

Answer (score 2):

Frame your question more as flying on Thursday night, not Friday morning (more for travellers rather than embassy officials). The people at the embassy will only consider it as Thursday night.

Shouldn't be a problem as most hotels let you checkout at around 1400-1500 hrs. So a 10 hrs wait for flight shouldn't be big deal.

> As a side note: I read somewhere that if you book more hotel bookings than the intended period of stay your visa can be refused.

Yes, why would you do that? It makes you look like an overstayer and visa will be promptly refused.